# How to change absolute path to relative in .jsx file. (Photoshop extension script)?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

I have a problem while developing an extension for Photoshop.
I have generated action code that I write in a .jsx file. I need to change the absolute path to a relative one so that the user has access to the file, regardless of where the extension was installed.

.jsx file:

```
function step7(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putInteger(cTID('Idnt'), 4);
    desc1.putPath(cTID('null'), new File("~/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/CEP/extensions/Mockups_Extension/psd/texture.png"));
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('FTcs'), cTID('QCSt'), sTID("QCSAverage"));
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc2.putUnitDouble(cTID('Hrzn'), cTID('#Pxl'), -1.13686837721616e-13);
    desc2.putUnitDouble(cTID('Vrtc'), cTID('#Pxl'), 0);
    desc1.putObject(cTID('Ofst'), cTID('Ofst'), desc2);
    desc1.putUnitDouble(cTID('Wdth'), cTID('#Prc'), 249.5);
    desc1.putUnitDouble(cTID('Hght'), cTID('#Prc'), 249.5);
    executeAction(cTID('Plc '), desc1, dialogMode);
  };
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your extension path from CEP-side.

CEP:

```
//when initialization happens
var extensionRoot = csInterface.getSystemPath(SystemPath.EXTENSION);
csInterface.evalScript('updateGlobalVars("' + extensionRoot + '")', function() {
    csInterface.evalScript('step7()');
});
```

JSX:

```
var pathToExtension = '';

function updateGlobalVars(path) {
    pathToExtension = path;
};

function step7(arg1, arg2) {
    alert(pathToExtension)
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But the problem is that if we use this option in the **myScript** function, then the **step7** function (in my example) does not see the variables of the **myScript** function. Therefore, I need to somehow integrate your option into the existing **step7** function or create global variable.

Comment: And what stops you from creating a global variable or passing this path to your `step7` function?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to create a global variable, since this does not work as in js. The function does not return the result to a variable. I would be grateful if you show how to create **a global variable** and how **to pass the path to the existing step7 function**.

Comment: I've updated my answer. That's quite a basic thing so I'd recommend to spend an hour and take a free JS course on any learning platform just to make your life easier :)

Comment: I already tried this option, but in JSX the global variable doesn’t work like in JS.
If I write alert in the **updateGlobalVars** function, everything output.
And if I write alert in the **step7** function, it does not output.

Comment: it does work, I have exactly the same setup in my extensions.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of an alert from a test function inside jsx: https://prnt.sc/pi9qts and here're my functions, CEP: https://prnt.sc/pi9r15 and JSX: https://prnt.sc/pi9r5d

Comment: Maybe edit your question with more code: both on CEP side and JSX side with declaring and setting the variables? There could be something else that's wrong.

Comment: I created a new extension so that there is no extra code and checked your code. This works, but not always, alert displays either an empty message or a path. In random order. It can output an empty message 3 times, and for the 4th time it output a path.

Comment: CEP: 
`(function () {
    'use strict';
    var csInterface = new CSInterface();
    
    function init() {
        themeManager.init(); 
        var extensionRoot = csInterface.getSystemPath(SystemPath.EXTENSION) + "/psd/texture.png";
        csInterface.evalScript('updateGlobalVars("' + extensionRoot + '")');
        csInterface.evalScript('step7()');      
    }
    init();
}());`

Comment: JSX:

`var pathToExtension = '';

function updateGlobalVars(path) {
    pathToExtension = path;
    //alert(pathToExtension);
};

function step7() {
    alert(pathToExtension);
};`

Comment: To me this works as expected. I wonder if that's an issue with asynchronicity on your end for some reason. I've updated my answer (the cep side), could you try this version? This makes sure that step7 plays after updateGlobalVars has finished

Comment: Yes, it works !!! Always!
Thank you so much! You helped me a lot. This was a problem that stopped the entire development process. Thank you for your time and patience. Good luck in developing your projects!